# p-harmonic function vanishing on open set

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, be a p-harmonic function that vanishes (or has vanishing gradient) on an open subset of $\Omega$.

Is it true that $f$ must be a constant, and is there a reference for that?

Comment: I seem to recall hearing in a talk by Juan J. Manfredi that the problem is open for $n\geq 3$. Sorry I don't have a reference; you might try searching papers by Manfredi.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Manfredi indeed proved this for $n=2$ and for $n\geq 3$ it is an open problem whether two $p$-harmonic functions that agree on an open set are identical.